# Upgradeing mysql on centos 7 with virtualmin

Tags: centos, mysql, virtualmin

I have a running centos 7.2 with virtualmin, mysql 5.5.47
I would like to upgrade the database to a newer version.
How should I do it without breaking anything ?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using the official CentOS repos, there shouldn't be any problems.

That said, consider the following:

1. Ensure you have a good, tested backup of the system before upgrading along with a quick way to revert your changes if the upgrade goes bad.
2. Fire up another server, deploy your database on that server, and test the upgrade there before deploying to prod.

Comment: so you do not recommend upgrading on the live server.... (I though it might work like upgrading php version)

Comment: No, I'm recommending that you *test* the upgrade procedure on a non-production box first, so you can ensure that things don't break. Then when you have the process sorted out, you can do it on production.